# Twilio Verify API Javascript

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm a novice that is looking to incorporate phone number token verification into an Alchemer survey using Javascript.  I am told that Alchemer needs the code to be written in Javascript for it to work.

Can someone please tell me if Twilio Verify code can be written in Javascript language?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

[Verify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify) *Select Node.js example

[Serverless Phone Verification with Twilio Verify and Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/blog/serverless-phone-verification)